# Selenium web driver test from bamboo in cloud for testing file upload

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, bamboo

I have a test where i need to automate file upload. I tried using impersonator , i also used a local file, everything works fine when i run the test in local computer. Also, to note, impersonator is failing in case of cross domain. So as a workaround i tried using a file that is under the build of bamboo-home folder. It works fine in local but my actual test runs in cloud which runs test through agent servers. Bamboo lets me access/ browse the files in the build folder of it but it doesn't allow me to upload the same. Trying to use impersonator to access files of agent server failed too. The problem here is also the same, i can browse the folders but cannot upload the files. Not sure if its read/write permission as i tried giving full access too. Anyone has any idea in resolving this? any workaround? I am also looking through sauce labs add on of bamboo.

Answer (score 1):

What does your upload element look like ? Is it a "file" type element ? 
If yes, then you should be able to do it using the following

When working with RemoteWebDriver in a grid setup

```
WebElement El = driver.findElement(By.id("uploadElement"));
((RemoteWebElement) El ).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector()); 
String file = "src/test/resources/foo.txt";
El.sendKeys(new File(file).getAbsolutePath());
```

When working with the other flavors of RemoteWebDriver in a local setup [ browser opens up in the same machine where the test runs ]

```
WebElement El = driver.findElement(By.id("uploadElement"));
String file = "src/test/resources/foo.txt";
El.sendKeys(new File(file).getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: hi krishnan, there is no setfiledetector under the methods of remotewebelement? why isnt it showing up under my remotewebelement?

Comment: I didnt quite get what you are asking. setFileLocator is part of RemoteWebElement.

See here for javadocs : http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html#setFileDetector-org.openqa.selenium.remote.FileDetector-

Comment: https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html

in c# i dont find .setfilelocator. The reference webdriver dll doesnt seem to have it. 
what am i missing?

Comment: To begin with, I think you are referring to very old docs. Selenium moved over to using github a long time ago.

I dont know much on .NET, but I did find this unit test from the selenium codebase.

See if that gives you some pointers https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/test/remote/RemoteWebDriverSpecificTests.cs#L39

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/KxmRZ8MkM4M

here if you see, its mentioned by another fellow automator that there is no such method in c#. i see you have already commented on this forum too nevertheless .. i dont find my answer :(

Comment: Did you read the comment by Jim Evans (He is the maintainer of the .NET bindings ) https://groups.google.com/d/msg/webdriver/KxmRZ8MkM4M/45CT4ID_WjQJ He has shared an example and that is the same sort of example that I shared from the selenium codebase (As a unit test)

Comment: well reading the comments says there is this functionality added. may be the method is non existent but there is a workaround.Thank you for your insight

Comment: What I was stating was from the Java bindings. I guess you are looking for the same in C# bindings. Hope what Jim has shared as an example works.

Comment: cant thank u enough. thanks.. well got me into right direction. i used impersonator and what not